# Обратная совместимость новой интеграции шрифтов

Tags: android, шрифты

Читаю [эту статью](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/341218/). Немного не понял её часть:

> Обратите внимание: я сразу добавил в пример то как должен выглядеть файл, если вы хотите поддерживать и более старые версии Андроида. (Начиная с 14). Если вам повезло и у вас таргет только на супер-новые девайсы, то ваш файл сократится в 2 раза

Получается, эта фича не имеет обратной совместимости и её можно использовать **только с API 26**? Если нет, то объясните, какой тогда код использовать. И что имелось ввиду под **таргет**? `targetSdkVersion`? Причём он тут?

Comment: Эта фича имеет обратную совместимость с помощью support library 26 версии (вплоть до api level 14).

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного:

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/myfont-Regular"
          app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
    <font android:fontStyle="italic" android:fontWeight="400" android:font="@font/myfont-Italic"
          app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Italic" />
</font-family>
```

Вот только не понял, через какой неймспейс прописать `fontFamily` в теге `TextView`